# Find a best practice for Business Intelligent data processing

Tags: java, design-patterns, business-intelligence, data-processing

I'm working in a system that manages human resources and it has a BI (Business Intelligent) part to collect and process data from main system, then visualize processed data into charts, tables, ..

For example, we want to see the relation between person age [in range 18 - 38] (in axis 1) and their monthly salary (in axis 2) [in full salary range]. The aggregation value is counting in person. There is also an additional step called Filter, to filter the result only in the organization A.

The expected result is like this:

```
                 Age_18<28   Age_28<38 Age_38<48
Salary_<1000         12          25       45
Salary_1000<5000     12          10       2
Salary_>5000         1           1        2
```

The current processing steps are as below:

1. Search for axis1: Search all people with age range [18-38] in organization A
2. Search for axis2: Seach all people in in organization A
3. Merge results for axis1 and axis 2
4. Counting people for each condition,  for example number of people that has Age_18<28 AND Salary_<1000 is 12, and so on.
5. Convert to json response

Because there are a lot of cases to handle, the logic becomes complicated to maintain. All steps are handled manually like above.

So I just wonder if this is a common problem and should have a common way to handle, For example a design pattern, or algorithm, or library (Java) or a specific concept to handle such things that I never know before.

Target:
 - make code more simple, readable and maintainable
 - easy to extend, i.e add new cases

What I'm about to try:
- Apply chain of responsibility + strategy patterns
- Just wonder if Apache Kafka would be the right way

Note: the above is just a very simple case, it might contains multiple items in 1 axis, with some additional conditions

Comment: If you just want to work on the data with filtering and sorting, you can use something like jquery `datatable`. They provide functions like filtering, sorting, grouping and can also export data to PDF and Excel.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel - just choose suitable BI solution for this purpose where you'll able to configure pivot table reports like this without need to write & maintain java code.

Comment: But actually this is a legacy BI system and my job is to improve and maintain it

Comment: "Best practice" would be to not do that :-)   But actually, https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of this is that you are accumulating counts in a 3 x 3 frequency table.

1. Write a simple method to map the salary to an index as follows:

   ```
     < 1000         => 0
     1000 to < 5000 => 1
     >= 5000        => 2
   ```

   There are various ways to code this method.
2. Write a simple method to map the age to an index as follows:

   ```
     18 to < 28     => 0
     28 to < 38     => 1
     38 to < 48     => 2
   ```
3. Put it together like this:

   ```
     int counts[][] = new int[3][3];
     for each person: p in ...
         counts[ageIndex(p.age)]][salaryIndex(p.salary)] += 1;
   ```

You could easily implement that in Java, and probably in SQL or in your BI system's query language as well .. if it has one.

You can generalize this to M x M, and more dimensions.  If you put it in bit of effort about it, you can actually implement the mappings as a data driven function; e.g.

```
 public int mapToIndex(int value, int[] ranges) { ... }
```

---

Note there is a flaw in what you are doing.  Employees could be younger than 18 or older than 48.